# How to use structural search in IDEA to find lines without a trailing comment or comment that doesn't match a pattern

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

The requirement is that all static and not final variables are marked with a corresponding trailing comment, that contains a certain text (e.g. "TEXT")

I used the already existing template in IDEA "static fields that are not final", which works fine and added a comment with a text constraint.

```
static $Type$ $Variable$ = $Init$; // $Comment$
```

As a constraint for **$Comment$** I used a text constraint with the regex **!(.*TEXT.*)**

Unfortunately, is doesn't work. A line:

```
private static String ABC = "ABS" // TEXT
```

is still marked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seem like that should work. Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: I tried it on community 2020.2.3.